# C++ Darts Game: Loop does not exit second time round

Tags: c++, loops

I am currently coding a simulator for a game (or multiple games) of 501 darts in C++ and have run into a problem in my code.

The purpose of this region is to simulate 10,000 matches of world championship final darts between two players. One match consists of two players playing the best of 13 sets (first to 7), a set being the best of 5 games (first to 3). In each game both players start at a score of 501 and try to reduce their score to 0 before the other player. I am simulating 10,000 of these matches in order to gain the frequency of each possible result between the two players.

My players are declared in a class with their skill attributes and score count etc, with a method throw_quick_set(); which simulates the player throwing a set of 3 darts for their turn before the other player steps up to do the same.

My problem is, after the first match is won (the program sees a player with 7 sets) - the second match goes on forever with a player winning an infinite amount of sets. I see this because of the output phrases I included when a player wins a game or set when I noticed something was going wrong.

Perhaps someone can help me spot the error in my code, I've been staring at it so long I probably wouldn't notice it even if it was staring me in the face.

Thanks for your time!

```
int results[14] = {0}; //Stores counters for each of 14 possible outcomes

    for (int gameNum = 0; gameNum < 10000; gameNum++)
    {
        // Calculate results of 10,000 full world championship finals.
        // Final is thirteen sets - each set is a best of 5 games.
        int sidSetWins = 0, joeSetWins = 0;
        int sidGWins = 0, joeGWins = 0;


        do
        { // Play best of 13 sets

            do
            { // Play best of 5 games               

                do
                { // Play single game
                    if (currTurn == sid)
                    {
                        Sid.throw_quick_set(); // Throws a set of three
                        currTurn = joe;
                    }
                    else if (currTurn == joe)
                    {
                        Joe.throw_quick_set(); // Throws a set of three
                        currTurn = sid;
                    }
                }
                while ((Sid.score != 0) && (Joe.score != 0));

                if (Sid.score == 0)
                {
                sidGWins++;
                cout << "Sid wins game" <<  endl;
                Sid.score = 501;
                Joe.score = 501;
                }
                else if (Joe.score == 0)
                {
                joeGWins++;
                cout << "Joe wins game" << endl;
                Sid.score = 501;
                Joe.score = 501;
                }

                Sleep(1000);
            } 
            while ((joeGWins < 3) && (sidGWins < 3));

            if (joeGWins == 3)
            {
                joeSetWins++;
                cout << "Joe wins set" << endl;
                sidGWins = 0; 
                joeGWins = 0; // Reset for each set
            }
            else if (sidGWins == 3)
            {
                sidSetWins++;
                cout << "Sid wins set" << endl;
                sidGWins = 0; 
                joeGWins = 0; // Reset for each set
            }

            Sleep(1000);
        }
         while ((sidSetWins < 7) && (joeSetWins < 7));

         if ((gameNum%1000) == 0)
         {
             cout << "SidSets " << sidSetWins << endl;
             cout << "JoeSets " << joeSetWins << endl;
             sidSetWins = 0;
             joeSetWins = 0; // Reset for each match
         }
```

EDIT: Here's the class method throw_live_set(); also, if that helps you.

```
    int Darts_501::throw_quick_set() 
{ // Used for quick games with no commentary - for average calculations

    darts = 0;
    int startScore = score;

    quickGame = true; // Disable commentary

    do
    {
        if (score>=100)
            curr_state = fast;
        else if (score > 50)
            curr_state = slow;
        else if ((score <= 50) && (score > 1))
            curr_state = focus;
        else if ((score == 1) || (score < 0))
            curr_state = bust;
        else
            curr_state = out;

        switch (curr_state) 
        {
            case fast:  
                        score -= throw_treble(20, trebPerc);    
                break;

            case slow:  
                        score -= throw_single(20);
                break;

            case focus: 
                        if (score == 50)
                            score -= throw_bull(bullPerc);
                        else if ((score != 0) && (score%2 == 0))
                            score -= throw_double(score/2); // If score is even, look to hit the double of half that value
                        else if ((score != 0) && (score%2 != 0))
                            score -= throw_setup(score); // If odd, look to set-up a good double score (strategic) 
                break;

            case bust:
                        score = startScore;
                break;

            case out:   score = 0;;
        }
        darts++; 

    } while ((darts < 3) && 
        (curr_state != out) && 
            (curr_state != bust));  

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't see anything to reset their `Sid.score` and `Joe.score`, could it be that? (unless that is definitely handled in `throw_quick_set()`)

Comment: I suggest you show your other parts of the code as well.

Comment: @Kvothe You have noticed an error there! I borrowed the throw_quick_set() code from another portion of the program that simulates a single 501 game live and commentates it. So there was no reset of the score. That explains why whoever won the first game won all the rest!! I've now reset each players score after each game is won. However, although the game is more competitive now, the second set is still not won.

Comment: You should have spotted that error when you tried to run a single set, and corrected it,  before trying a match or a thousand matches. Start small and simple, build up in small steps, test at every step and *never add to code that doesn't work.*

Comment: @Beta Yes, it seems very silly now. Definitely lesson learned. Thanks

Comment: @CammyMcPherson Ensure one match works fine, then try doing a few in a loop (rather than 10000 instantly) and if the loop doesn't give the results you expect get it to print the values of all important variables at several points so you can see where they aren't what you expect. (If you have a modern debugger then you can step through it with that and it becomes trivial)